# How do I verify myself when using Python request posts

Tags: python, post, request, ssl-certificate

I can login and get a website, and post some messages. But on the other hand, some of the post calls failed, and the website return a message, which ask me to login again.

I think the reason is that I do not verify myself while posting, and the server find it and break this connection. But how to? I'm using mac and python 2.7.
I use this code to login:

```
 Connection = requests.session()
 result = Connection.post(url, headers = headd, data = data)
```

and success

This is other post codes after I login:

```
 result = Connection.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)
```

but failed.

I also tried this:

```
 result = Connection.post(url, headers = headers, data = data, verify=False)
```

But failed again. The url here is an https website. Does it matter? I mean, how to verify myself if necessary. Because I think it's the website who reject the post and break the session.

Comment: Can you please post the full code, the web-link so that I can see what is missing

Comment: result = Connection.post(url, headers = headd, data = data, verify=False)          This is how I post my request. Before this post, I can do Connection.get(url = url_0)                  And after this post, I do Connection.get(url = url_0) again, but this get failed and the website ask me to login. So I think it's this post action failed and caused me unlogin. I think I should verify myself when post. But how?

Comment: There is nothing to do with other codes, the problem is in the post

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
s = requests.session()
s.post(url, headers = headers, data = data)
```

instead of

```
Connection.post(...)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but "name 'session' is not defined"

Comment: Thank you very much~ I've edited the question, too. The Connection varaiable in my code is  same as s in your code

Comment: maybe you are posting the data in a bad way - which could lead to "please login" response

Comment: Maybe~ I would check it. But if so, what's the function of the "verify" parameter of post?

Comment: try to inspect how a "regular" browser post that data and make sure you are posting it the same way, maybe by printing the data?

are you sure that the data should be sent in a dictionary\ form-encoded data ?

Comment: In a "regular" browser, post information: Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7
Cookie: aliyungf_tc=AQAAAGPy62TYmQwArERvprXHoX8SXfqy; acw_tc=AQAAAIZRmE/VxgwArERvpuFHJEOWVhoI; current=-1; Hm_lvt_da198049956ebbe4cfe6ed29eb0af62d=1511535318; Hm_lpvt_da198049956ebbe4cfe6ed29eb0af62d=1511535385; remember_username=MTg4MTA3NTgzMTk%3D; lzh_think_language=zh-CN; hjstoken=EjzUwx1MxPSfX0BQny5I8w%3D%3D_EjzUwx1MxPSfX0BQny5I8w%3D%3D_1511638951_296c7de52ca55b3dd78d5de2da774e97_asC6KuCSTnrpM1JkPFDJkE9Ux5YiRCC%2B6ao9d1ULaSo%3D; PHPSESSID=im6uggfm8gpg31me372b1uoda2

Comment: so head = {"Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7", " Cookie": {"aliyungf_tc": "AQAAAGPy62TYmQwArERvprXHoX8SXfqy"...}}